# Identifying the end of a slow-start phase

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming

I have a good understanding of slow-start phase, namely how it only lets a few packets send at first, however this amount increments until the max is found in order to avoid congestion.

For the graph below however, how do I identify when the slow-start phase ends? I'm assuming it starts right in the beginning at 0 seconds, which is when the connection would be established. I'm going to guess that the slow-start ends at 0.65 seconds? Which is when we only start seeing two dots (packets) one after another... Or rather would this just be because of congestion avoidance?

[image]

Comment: Consider embedding the image on Stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

I agree. It would be easier if you had joined the dots, but I see maximum slope being achieved at t=0.65s, then a slowdown as congestion avoidance kicks in.

Comment: Right - this is the one, I misinterpreted the figure.

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat hard to see (no gridlines on the figure), but it seems the max window size is reached around ~0.76s (150000 bytes) - so slow start ends there.

Comment: How did you figure that? There is no data present on maximum window size. And what does maximum window size, which comes from the receiver, have to do with slow start, which happens at the sender?

Comment: There's a dot at the far right side of the figure, at the same y value as the previous one. I meant the congestion window.